# Use pydub with AWS-stored files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pydub

I want to concatenate two files I'm storing in AWS, save them as .wav and pass them to IBM's Speech-to-Text API.
This is how a normal call to IBM looks like.

```
with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'audio-file.wav'),
               'rb') as audio_file:
    recognition_job = speech_to_text.create_job(
        audio_file,
        content_type='audio/wav',
        timestamps=True
    ).get_result()
```

Can pydub export directly to AWS, as online I cannot have it stored locally?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you say "export to AWS" I assume you mean to [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). From there you want to invoke IBM's speech-to-text API. To interact with Amazon S3 in python you should use the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) SDK.

You don't need to export your data to a temporary local file if you don't need it. You can keep the data in memory in python.

```
import os
import io

import boto3
from pydub import AudioSegment
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1()

s3r = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = "randall-stackoverflow"

file1 = io.BytesIO()
s3r.Object(bucket, "file1.wav").download_fileobj(file1)
file2 = io.BytesIO()
s3r.Object(bucket, "file2.wav").download_fileobj(file2)

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav(file1)
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav(file2)

combined = sound1.append(sound2) # maybe add crossfade
recognition_job = speech_to_text.create_job(
    combined.raw_data,
    content_type='audio/wav',
    timestamps=True
)
```

I'd be remiss if I didn't mention [Amazon Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) which would let you do all of this within the AWS cloud.

```
transcribe = boto3.client("transcribe")
url = "{}/{}/{}".format(
    s3r.meta.client.meta.endpoint_url,
    bucket,
    "file1.wav"
)
transcribe.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName="ExampleJob",
    Media={"MediaFileUri": url},
    LanguageCode="en-US",
    MediaFormat="wav"
)
```